# SSIS package in SQL Server 2005 can send data to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis, package

I Have an SSIS package in SQL Server 2005 that takes data from a flat file and puts it in a table in SQL Server 2005. Now I want it to send it to an additional location along with the 2005 location. This new table is in SQL Server 2008. Can it be done without porting my SSIS package to SQL Server 2008?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your 2005 package write to 2008 database without upgrading.

Comment: But the OLEDB Connection Manager does not connect to a 2008 data base.

Comment: Thank you. Also this was a non issue. The OLEDB Connection manager in SSIS 2005 can connect to 2008 SQL Server database. Tried both out.SQLNCLI has issues with not having the same data type in dealing with dates.